# expected number of throws to get six

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I am looking on the solution to this problem presented in the book  *"Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions"* by Mosteller (p.18-19).

> On average, how many times must a die be thrown until one gets a 6?

There are many ways to solve this problem as this is simple example of a geometric distribution, but I don't quite get the trick the author did it with the $qm$. 

 **I am looking for explanation/interpretation of this trick (transition (2) (3) )**? 


The first expression is clear, it is just the expansion of the expected value definition

(p be the probability of a 6 on a given trial)

$$ m = p + 2 pq + 3pq^2 + 4pq^3 + ... \quad \quad \quad  (1)$$

Further the "trick" with qm has been used 

$$qm =\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  pq + 2pq^2 + 3pq^3 + ...  \quad \quad \quad  (2)$$
so that
$$m - qm = p + pq + pq^2 + ...  \quad \quad \quad  (3)$$
$$m(1-q) = 1  \quad \quad \quad  (4)$$
$$m=\frac{1}{p}  \quad \quad \quad  (5)$$

Comment: You're most likely going to have to share the problem with us.

Comment: I am guessing your question is to find the expected number of throws of a dice to get a six on the dice (It should be explicitly stated in the question though). Could you explain what $p,q$ and $m$ are in the expression. Also is the dice fair?

Comment: What do you not understand ? Please be more specific.

Comment: @callculus Not everybody on stackexchage has the book at hand, could you explicitly state the problem and the solution you are providing. From your question almost nothing is clear.

Comment: @HarshCurious I´m not the questioner.

Comment: @callculus sorry, my bad!

Comment: You have identified a "trick" with $qm$. You say you do not fully understand this "trick", but you must know _something_ about it or you would not identify it as a known "trick". To get an answer that explains the part of the trick you did not understand, I recommend you more fully explain everything about the trick that you _do_ understand. Then we can more easily see what you need.

Comment: @ David K, if you check the reference you will see that this transition is called a trick by the author of the book. All the steps of the solution are taken from this book. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, $m$ in here is an [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence). Each term in $m$ is a arithmetico-geometric sequence, which is a combination of arithmetic progression $a_{n+1}=d+a_n$ ($1,2,3,4, \cdots$) and geometric progression $a_{n+1}=ra_n$ ($q,q^2,q^3, \cdots $)

The trick that the author used is a well-known way to calculate the sum of all the terms in the arithmetico-geometric sequence. (if you look at the wikipedia link above, you can see that it also use the same trick to find sum).

In conclusion, it is a well-known trick used in calculating arithmetic, geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

This "trick" it is maybe not only used once. To calculate

$p\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^k=p + pq + pq^2 + ...$ you firstly can evaluate the partial sum.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} q^k=1+q+q^2+q^3+\ldots +q^{n-1}+$

$q\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n} q^k=q+q^2+q^3+\ldots +q^{n-1}+q^{n}$

Here the trick is very similar. Calculating the difference of the two equations above.

$(1-q)\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n} q^k=1-q^{n}$

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} q^k=\frac{1}{1-q}-\frac{q^{n}}{1-q}$

$p\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n} q^k=\frac{p}{1-q}-\frac{p\cdot q^{n}}{1-q}=1-\frac{p\cdot q^{n}}{1-q}$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} 1-\frac{p\cdot q^{n}}{1-q}=1-0=1$

You can call it a trick. And  you sould have seen it before you apply it- maybe in another context. To figure out by yourself is  not usual I would say.